# java Date class - Why I have other date output in these lines?

Tags: java, date

My code:

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
 Date date = new Date();

System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
System.out.println(sdf.format(sdf.parse(sdf.format(date))));
```

and this output I get:

```
2013-02-08 15:48:37
2013-12-30 15:48:37
```

expected output:

```
2013-02-08 15:48:37
2013-02-08 15:48:37
```

look at the day and month of date

Comment: You are using a logging library that outputs a standard log format with the date, time, and log level you used.  If you want a normal output, use System.out.println or something similar.

Comment: Because log.info logs the date and the logging type.

Comment: I guess OP is looking for reason why date is changed when doing double formatting and not regarding additional components in the output.

Comment: The question got even more confusing.

Comment: Please provide an expected output compared to your real output to trully understand this question.

Comment: @Eldar I tried in `java.util.logging` and there is no change at all. What logging framework you are using?

Comment: I dont know why a (correct) answer was downvoted and finally removed, but the issue is indeed the format specifier: use "yyyy" instead of "YYYY"

Comment: What does `sdf.parse(sdf.format(date))` display ?

Comment: @Andreas: The question was edited. The first version asked a question almost entirely unrelated to the current question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the method "parse"

==> "Parses text from the beginning of the given string to produce a date. The method may not use the entire text of the given string. "

```
The method may not use the entire text of the given string.
```

I've run your code and got the following :

```
System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
System.out.println(sdf.parse(sdf.format(date)));
System.out.println(sdf.format(sdf.parse(sdf.format(date))));
```

Result :

```
2013-02-08 14:54:39
Mon Dec 31 14:54:39 CET 2012
2013-12-31 14:54:39
```

As you can see the parse function converts the time correctly, but not the date itself. I think it is not intended to be used that way and therefore produces a weird result.

However, this is the first time I notice this, so I will not be able to give more details :)

Answer (score 1):

To keep things simple, lets use a basic test case:

```
String date = "2013-02-08 15:48:37";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(sdf.parse(date));

// Output: Mon Dec 31 15:48:37 CET 2012
```

According to the [SimpleDateFormat Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), the format specifier `Y` is used to denote the "Week year". The correct format specifier for the "Year" is `y` - with this, we get the correct output:

```
sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(sdf.parse(date));

// Output: Fri Feb 08 15:48:37 CET 2013
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `log` is some kind of a logger, its standard practice for them to print out the time date and log level for every line. It makes it easier to debug from the log if need be,

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = new Date();

    Logger log = Logger.getLogger("InfoLogging");

    log.info(sdf.format(date));
    try {
        log.info(sdf.format(sdf.parse(sdf.format(date))));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Gives output:

```
Feb 8, 2013 2:57:09 PM javaapplication2.JavaApplication2 main
INFO: 2013-02-08 14:57:08
Feb 8, 2013 2:57:09 PM javaapplication2.JavaApplication2 main
INFO: 2013-02-08 14:57:08
```

Which Logger are you using?

Comment: Note that OP used "YYYY" (which means "Week Year", not "Year" according to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) - with this, I can reproduce the behaviour

Comment: Ok OP uses 1.7. I have 1.6 so YYYY throws exception.